# Projecting model training time using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, train

I'd like to use R's random forest package on a rather large dataset.  I'm anticipating to this to take a while (perhaps more time than I want to deal with).  Is there a way to display the estimated training time in R?  If it helps, I'm using RStudio if there might be any extra bells and whistles that might help there.

Comment: No, there is not. And for large data use either the rborist or ranger package. both run in parallel and can handle large datasets better.

Comment: @phiver Thanks for the tip!  I actually moved to caret and am using its parallel option (has sped stuff up).  Would that be advisable?  Or would you still recommend the other two?

Comment: You're welcome. Both options are also available in caret, methods rborist or ranger.